# jQuery change div content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I need help changing my code so that it changes div content on click to link id
example: I click first link, it prints out 1 and so one. And also it will have an unique link #first.
Also by default it shows "default"

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.bbq.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
  tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

  $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash || '#first';

    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(hash).show();
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');
  });

  $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
});
</script>
<ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a href="#first" id="1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second" id="2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third" id="3">Third</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs">
    Change content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.hash` normally returns an empty string when there is no hash, and you need to check the anchors `href`, not `hash`. It does'nt look like the anchors are inside the `.tabs` element either ?

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        var tabContainers = $('.tabs > div'),
            hash = window.location.hash != '' ? window.location.hash : '#first';

        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(hash).show();
        $('.tabNavigation li a').removeClass('selected');
        $('a[href="' + hash + '"]', '.tabNavigation').addClass('selected');
    }).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

I'm gussing you actually have elements with ID's matching the anchors href inside `.tabs`, and that is't not empty like in the example?

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RHFUr/)

Comment: I'm looking for if I add new line <a href="#forth" id="4">Forth</a> it shows 4 as result without any more modifications

Comment: You can add as many anchors you'd like, as long as the href matches an ID, this will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to remove these: <div id="first">FIRST</div> and print out id of a button that is clicked?

Comment: @sw0o0sh - Well, yes! But that has nothing to do with the hashchange, it's just a regular click function : `$('a').on('click', function() { alert(this.id); $(this).remove(); });`

Comment: Right. But what if I want to keep hash as well? So that if i go to index.php#third it shows third.

Comment: As long as you dont preventDefault or return false in the click function, that will still work?

Comment: Should run something like: $( this ).find( "div" ).html

Comment: @sw0o0sh - not sure what this is for, but if you click `<a>` elements, that code will look for `<div>` elements inside that `<a>` element and return the html inside those div's etc.

Comment: Whats messed up? It works like you'd expect it to, changing the HTML of .tabs to the number you get from the name="2" on the anchor ?

Comment: Okey, 1 last question. can I get the same effect with anchor as #first, #second... as clickin? Giving you best answer

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean, but yes, you can show and hide elements with javascript click events without using hashes at all. Here's an example -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RHFUr/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

`$('#1').click(function(){
  $('.tabs').html('Your Text');
})`

you can include this in a function which accepts the `id` and sets the value at the appropriate location in the dom tree

Since your `a` tag should not perform the default action, you should prevent `a` from the same.