# Insert custom text to many pages

Tags: html

I have a web store and there is a product description. I need to insert a custom text, like "This is the last piece!" - but I need it on 500 products. I can manually enter the HTML code for each product, but what code should I use when I want to change all the text at once?

So when I change the text from "This is the last piece!" to "ON SALE!" it should change for all 500 products.

Comment: You need to paste your code so it's easier for us to help you. And do you use a CMS system such as Wordpress, Magento etc. ?

Comment: Are you using any server language?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```css
.custom_text:before{content: "Custom text"}
```

```html
<p><span class="custom_text"></span> exercitation ullamco labori</p>
<p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <span class="custom_text"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sasikumar answered, but that would be using css and you would have to make sure the same class is used to store the former text. And one thing is that the text will **append** not totally replace it. Using javascript is best. Here is a related question [jQuery change div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162585/jquery-change-div-content)